# Scraping content from urls in dataframe using R

Tags: r, url, web-scraping, rvest

Sorry, I'm relatively new to R and don't know it very well yet. I have also seen that similar questions have been asked more often. However, the corresponding solutions did not work for me (or - more likels - I did not make them work).
I want to scrape content from a newspaper. Therefore, in a first step, i need to scrape all articles and the respective urls from an url. That works fine

```
Abendblatt <- read_html("https://www.abendblatt.de/archiv/nachrichten-vom-3-3-2016")
headline_ <- Abendblatt %>% 
  html_nodes(".teaser__headline") %>%
  html_text()
url_ <- Abendblatt %>% 
  html_nodes("article") %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_attr("href")
df_urls <- data.frame(headline = headline_, url = url_)
```

Now I have the urls from all the articles.
Next, I want to scrape specific contetn from the articles. For a single url that also works fine

```
Abendblatt_Article <- read_html("https://www.abendblatt.de/vermischtes/article227980833/Tatort-Muenster-Friederike-Kempter-hoert-als-Ermittlerin-auf.html")


header_ <- Abendblatt_Article %>% 
html_nodes(".article__header__headline") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  paste(., collapse = "")
intro_ <- Abendblatt_Article %>% 
  html_nodes(".article__header__intro__text") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  paste(., collapse = "")

text_ <- Abendblatt_Article %>% 
  html_nodes("p") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  paste(., collapse = "")
  
df <- data.frame(heading = header_, intro = intro_, text = text_)
```

However, I would like to loop over all urls in url_ from the dataframe df_urls.

Can anyone help me with that?

Many thanks

Jens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
library(rvest)

read_data <- function(url) {
  
  result <- tryCatch({

  Abendblatt_Article <- read_html(url)
  
  header_ <- Abendblatt_Article %>% 
    html_nodes(".article__header__headline") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    paste(., collapse = "")
  intro_ <- Abendblatt_Article %>% 
    html_nodes(".article__header__intro__text") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    paste(., collapse = "")
  
  text_ <- Abendblatt_Article %>% 
    html_nodes("p") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    paste(., collapse = "")
  
  data.frame(heading = header_, intro = intro_, text = text_)  
  
  }, error = function(e) data.frame(heading = NA, intro = NA, text = NA))
  
  return(result)
}

result <- purrr::map_df(df_urls$url, read_data)
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, thanks for your hint. That seems to be what I have been looking for. However, I get the following error message" Fehler in UseMethod("read_xml") : 
  nicht anwendbare Methode für 'read_xml' auf Objekt der Klasse "factor" angewendet " or in english "Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : 
  Inapplicable method for 'read_xml' applied to object of class "factor"." Do you have any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: @JensEger Ronak's solution should work. Being new to R this is already pretty advanced. If the function works for a single case, you use purrr::map_xxx friends to iterate over your data structure. Load the urls in a vector:, i.e. urls <- Abendblatt %>%  html_nodes("article") %>%  html_nodes("a") %>%  html_attr("href"). Then run result <- urls %>% purrr::map_df(.f = read_data)
Then check that this vector is of class character. You should see in the Global Environment pane in RStudio under the heading the urls vector and chr [1:200] ...
That means you have a character vector of 200 elements

Comment: Note that this strips of your headline that you may add to your result again, if needed. Just focus on the problem at hand and simplify your vectors/data.frame. I am not sure where the factor comes from, but it feels that R coerces text. So it is safer to work with the pure urls-vector for you. Viel Glück!

Comment: It feels like I'm making a stupid mistake. The first part of my code saves url_ as a vector with chr[1:200], this should be fine. The second part, however, saves Abendblatt_Article as a list. Which seems to work in the single case example, but not in the loop. Can you help me with defining Abendblatt_Article <- read_html(url_) as a vector?

Comment: @JensEger It seems that you are on R < 4.0.0. Try creating all the dataframe with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` like `df_urls <- data.frame(headline = headline_, url = url_, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` and also change the last call in `read_data` function to `data.frame(heading = header_, intro = intro_, text = text_, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` and try the answer again.

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you very much. I was not aware of the implications of the different R versions. The code seems to work now. However, I get the error Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404. which seems to mean that one of the URLs is not found. So I added try.Catch e.g. (Abendblatt_Article <- tryCatch(read_html(url))) and savely in result <- purrr::safely(map_df(df_urls$url, read_data))

However, I still get the same error message. Can you help me with this?